# Error: Can't open display

Tags: x-server, display-settings

I have several machines on my LAN and my main workstation called `lagrangian`. Machines can ping `lagrangian`. All machines can have

```
DISPLAY=lagrangian:0
```

set. I run `VcXsrv` on `lagrangian` and hence can run any XWindow applications of other machines, having windows displayed on `lagrangian`.

Except one. It says

```
Error: Can't open display:
```

What can be a reason?

Comment: Have you checked the error logs?

Answer (score 3):

The error message line ends with the value of the display it is trying to connect to.  Since there is nothing on the line you probably have failed to set the environment variable on that machine for some reason.  Try `printenv DISPLAY` to verify.  If it was correct it would print `lagrangian:0`, but I suspect it won't.

Comment: `printenv DISPLAY` isn't as portable as `echo $DISPLAY`. Just a note, in case he's not got your exact environment.

Comment: But it's not *quite* the same thing.  `echo $DISPLAY` will show also shell variables that are *not* exported to the environment.  If someone sets the variable without doing `export`, (s)he might be fooled if doing it with `echo`.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing `xhost +`.
In my case when I tried to run a grphaic application (ddd, a display debugger) with sudo, it gave me `can't open display :2`. The DISPLAY variable was set to `:2` (I was using vnc). Without sudo, ddd window comes up but it couldn't attach to the program I wanted to debug. So I tried `xhost +` and the ddd window came up ok also attaching to the program.